# Can I put a rack on a carbon road bike?

Tags: road-bike, carbon, rack

I got a carbon-framed [Kestrel Talon Road Bike](http://www.kestrelbicycles.com/road/talon-road-shimano-105) recently but I also want to use it for commuting to and from work and I want a place to put my lock and other stuff on the bike. Is it possible to have a rack on this kinda bike.

Comment: You've got various options for stashing things on your bike, or for wearing things, and I think they've probably all been covered on here over the years. If you're looking for inspiration, try searching through past questions.

Comment: I'd suggest a backpack. Or getting a different bike for commuting.

Comment: Carbon is sensitive to pressure, so clamping things around poles is not recommended.  You'd want to use any mounting lugs that are already in your frame, or possbibly a rack that fastens to your seat clamp bolt and rear axles if there are no mounting lugs.   Or keep the carbon bike for fun and use a separate commuter bike  (mind you since I got my road bike, the commuter MTB hasn't left the shed for a month)

Comment: Can you leave your stuff at work?  Only take a lock with you if you're going somewhere its needed (and a nice carbon bike probably shouldn't be left in the rack stands else someone pinches it.)   So take your commuter bike to those places.

Comment: If you are going to buy a bag for carrying stuff on your body, courier bags are specifically bad to be comfortable and accessible while on the bike.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is (strongly) not advisable to put a rack on carbon.

You could probably put a lock mount on the handlebar stem (I do).

You could get an over-sized seat bag.

Possibly a handlebar bag.

Bottle cage bag but they don't have much capacity.  They are good for like wallet, cell phone, and keys.

Don't like to do product recommendations but [Revelatedesigns](https://www.revelatedesigns.com) have a lot of bags.

Not easy to find but there are [carbon forks with rack eyelets](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/20461/will-using-a-pannier-rack-mounting-kit-damage-a-carbon-frame-axiom-vs-tubus). But I would not do that to that bike.

Not a typical commuter bike.

Comment: Got it. Any recommendations on a Bike Lock mount and Lock combo. 
I have abus locks u lock right now for another bike but I am in the market for one

Comment: I use a good old Kryptonite on the stem mounted with U going down and it loops the handlebar.

Comment: Another option is to leave a lock at work.  A good lock is heavy.  There are a number of question on the site on how deal with commuting.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest looking at frame bags. They don't carry much, but they have more capacity than the more sensible under-seat bags. You can get various sizes (up to 'fill the triangle'), and could even do both a frame bag and a seat bag.

[image]

There's a cycle tourist with a carbon bike a [bit heavier than yours here](https://www.crazyguyonabike.com/doc/?doc_id=14155) so it can be done. Most of the carbon bike people tape their frames where the bag will rub to prevent the bag slowly grinding through the frame, but that seems to be the main concern.

Answer (score 4):

I have a rack on Carbon Fiber Trek 5000 series frame.  It's been there for around 7 years.   I did it by drilling and tapping holes into the rear dropouts, which are aluminum.  So none of the weight is on the frame at all — it's taken by the wheel directly.  A single stay at the top anchors the rack to the brake bolt.

Now, I would not think of using the bike for a loaded tour.  But for holding my briefcase on for a trip to the office: no problem at all.

Of course, many newer carbon frames don't have a flat place on the dropout where you could do this.  A better alternative might be a racks that mounts to the axle, attached by the QR skewer.

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @Squire. Nice first answer. We recommend that new members take the [tour] to get the most out of the site. Cheers

Comment: Good work pointing out clearly that its into the metal dropouts and not the carbon fibre frame.

Comment: I was thinking about doing the same thing but anchoring to the seat post.  Do you think that would be able to hold a bit more?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can put a rack on a CF frame, given the right rack. Namely, [Tailfin](https://www.tailfin.cc/) makes racks explicitly designed to work with CF frames without rack eyelets, like "racing" road bikes.
[image]

Comment: Heard this recently mentioned in a Video. The guy sounded satisfied. He also used a carbon bike for commuting.

Answer (score 2):

You could get a beam rack that attaches to a seat post. Only issue is that you'll be limited by weight you can carry.

If you have a
https://www.sjscycles.co.uk/carriers-racks/tubus-adapter-set-for-quick-release-axle-mounting/

https://www.tredz.co.uk/.M-Part-Seat-Clamp-Mount_34111.htm?sku=79197&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=google_shopping&gclid=Cj0KCQjwyJn5BRDrARIsADZ9ykEEpZRlvyZUEBcTRVOSNHR2I2tft31vzRVSBLG6GW9dD0YVcvufXaQaAlmbEALw_wcB

Then stress is transferred off the brittle frame.  Toured like this on a carbon frame. Just be prepared for fun and games when changing an inner tube.