# Can i put a rack for panniers on a Carbon road bike w/ Thru axle?

Tags: road-bike, rack, panniers

I was looking at getting a new Trek Domane SL 5 for commuting, but i don't see any way to mount a rack on it? I need to carry a laptop bag and a change of cloths. Is there any way to do this on that bike?

Comment: By not getting a Trek Domane SL, that's how.

Comment: Sounds like you want to ride a race bike for commuting.  Probably better to focus on a bike frame that offers what you need (mudguards, rack, lots of lights/reflectors) and leave the fairweather road bike at home for races and training rides.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I put a rack on a carbon road bike?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/35807/can-i-put-a-rack-on-a-carbon-road-bike) and several other "rack on carbon bike" questions.

Comment: @user50823 your question in indeed a duplicate (see the comment above mine), I've added an additional answer to it, please check it out.

Comment: The question is a duplicate, but I think in the meantime there are a lot more solutions for thru axles available.